How to move between view controllers?
I have first view controller with navigation bar. Next I go to second view controller with navigation bar. And next I want to go to third view controller with navigation bar and overCurrentContext options. And in third view controller I want to my back button return to first view controller. I use this code to do it:
In second vc:
let detailViewController = ThirdVC()
self.navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: false)

In third vc for back button:
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)

But I can't see second vc as a background of third vc. .overCurrentContext doesn't work. I see gray background. How to fix it?

@AlexSmith Your original question was better than your edit. Since you want a clear background on ThirdVC, you have to present it, not push it. So now your issue is how to pop SecondVC when you dismiss ThirdVC.

@DonMag The OP needs to present, not push, ThirdVC since the OP wants ThirdVC to have a clear background. modalPresentationStyle is not used when a VC is pushed, only when presented.

@HangarRash Yes. That's the question. When I return on button click I need to dismiss third vc and second vc.

@HangarRash I think original question was better than your edit. But DonMag and  DuncanC didn't understand the question. So I simplified it.

@AlexSmith Where is the dismiss button? In the SecondVC or the ThirdVC?

@HangarRash It is a custom back button in navigation bar with this code self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false) in ThirdVC

@AlexSmith - Navigate from FirstVC to SecondVC using push ... them either: present ThirdVC (with transparency) and use a Closure or Delegate/Protocol pattern to have ThirdVC's "close" button tell SecondVC to pop back to First. Or, load ThirdVC as a child, add it's view as a subview, then navigation bar's default Back button action will take you back to FirstVC

@DonMag Thank you! I had already thought about similar options, but I thought there was an easier option. I'm surprised that I can't use push everywhere and .overCurrentContext with push for 3vc

@DonMag No need for a separate closure/delegate. You can make use of the delegate property of the presentationController to be notified when the presented VC will/did dismiss. This logic would go in the SecondVC in this case.

@AlexSmith - present presents a new controller on top of another controller. push pushes a new controller onto the navigation stack, and "pushes" the current controller off the screen. Two completely different tasks. As you can see, there are various ways to do this... although, you haven't told us anything about your actual goal. Does ThirdVC need to be a controller? You could possibly simplify things by adding whatever you're displaying in ThirdVC as a subview of SecondVC, start with it hidden, and then show it when desired. No need for any "close" button stuff.


.overFullScreen is a modalPresentationStyle, so It only work when you "present" the view modally. So it won't work with push, which push the ViewController into the navigation's stack.

In your case, if you really want to present the thirdVC modally and then pop to the rootViewController from secondVC as the secondVC has been push to the navigation's stack. You can achieve that by using delegate pattern to notify the secondVC to pop to re rootVC.

Another way is using closure as below:


In your thirdVC, declare a closure:
var onPopToRoot:(()-> Void)?

then in your pop function, for example:
@objc private func popToRoot() {
      onPopToRoot?()
      dismiss(animated: true)
}

In your secondVC:
@objc private func goThird() {
        let detailViewController = ThirdVC()
        self.navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        detailViewController.onPopToRoot = {[weak self] in
            self?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }
        self.present(detailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

